# AS3: add event listeners to loaded AS2 SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent, actionscript-2

What I am trying to do is - simply load an external SWF into my AS3 code.

I then want to show it on my stage - and be able to catch the 'ROLL_OVER', 'ROLL_OUT' and 'MOUSE_CLICK' events that happen with the SWF, meaning - I want to know when the user hovers over the loaded SWF and when he clicks on it.

If I load an external **AS3 SWF** - it all works fine, and I can trace the events successfully.

If I load an external **AS2 SWF** - in some types of AS2 banners I can catch the events, and in some - I can't.

It is important to note that I cannot control the loaded SWFs and I cannot code them in a different manner.

The way I load the external SWFs is like this:

.

```
var loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onLoaded);
loader.load(new URLRequest(externalSwfURL));

function onLoaded(evt:Event):void
{
    // The reason I don't create the MovieClip like this is because I need to support 
    // both AS2 and AS3 that will be loaded, and loaded AS2 cannot be casted to 'MovieClip'
    //var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(evt.target.content);  

    // This method allows me to load both external AS2 and AS3 SWF files
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    mc.addChild(loader);

    // Add the events that I want to track
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER    , onMouseEnterSWF);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT    , onMouseLeaveSWF);
    mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK    , onMouseClickSWF);

    mc.x = 100;
    mc.y = 100;

    stage.addChild(mc);
}
```

.

What I have found out is that if the loaded AS2 SWF has a transparent button on top of it (a lot of them have that) - then the mouse events aren't fired back up to my AS3 code ! They are somehow 'swallowed' inside the loaded AS2 SWF and not bubbled up.

If I try to load an AS3 SWF that has a transparent button as the top layer - it works, and still bubbles up the mouse events to my AS3 code.

Can anyone tell me why this happens ?

PS - if I load an AS2 SWF that doesn't have a transparent button as a top layer - than the mouse events ARE bubbled up to my AS3 code.

Here is a link to an AS2 SWF file that has the 'transparent button' that blocks the events from bubbling up to the AS3 code:
[link to AS2 SWF](http://www.filedropper.com/jdatebanner-copy)

Answer (score 0):

ActionScript 2 runs in a different virtual machine and is not compatible with ActionScript 3. Communication between the two SWFs ist not even not easy, but works only with a local connection. ActionScript 2 also doesn't have an event system so this would be the second part to take care of.

-> it can't work as you expect it to.

Comment: Can't I build a wrapper class in AS2 that loads the AS2 SWF and catches it's events and fires them up to the AS3 ?

Comment: No, because there are no events which get dispatched by the loaded ActionScript 2 SWF.

Comment: why does that happen ? how come in AS3 the  top-most-button continues to bubble-up the events and in AS2 the top-most-button catches the events and stops them from propogating up ?

Comment: Because ActionScript 2 and ActionScript 3 are two completely different things - the two languages and runtimes are not compatible with each other.